# Macro and function with same name in header file

Tags: c, macros

`tool.c`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "tool.h"

void safeFree(void** pp) {
    if (pp != NULL & *pp != NULL) {
        free(*pp);
        *pp = NULL;
    }
}
```

`tool.h`

```
#ifndef tool_h
#define tool_h

void safeFree(void** pp);
#define safeFree(p) safeFree((void**)&(p))

#endif /* tool_h */
```

I want to use the macro after I import `tool.h` in `main.c`, but the programme can't be compiled. Is there any way I could define macro and function with same name?

Comment: Think about how macro replacement works, then reconsider what you actually want.

Comment: Do you understand what a "macro" is?  It's a command to the preprocessor to replace all occurrences of `safeFree` with the specified replacement text.  How do you expect that to work?

Comment: This won't work; why don't you upper-case that macro name? or even what look like better, call the function directly

Comment: This is a duplicate of other questions — though it may take time to find one.  The short answer is that you should use `void (safeFree)(void **pp) { … }` to implement the function.

Comment: The cast is potentially dangerous, as the macro will happily take every type of integer or pointer argument.

Comment: Yes, I really don't understand how macros work. I'm reading a book about macros and pointers in C. I just saw this code block in the book. It works fine in the example (all codes in `main.c`), I'm curious what happened if I put the macro and function in another file.

Comment: so I asked this question. Maybe someone would think this is a silly question, but I really want to know why. OK, I'm punished by asking it, I don't regret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I could define macro and function with same name?

Not in the same compilation unit.

Besides, it is not a good practice. ***Don't do it***. If the macro is going to be your primary method of using the functionality, define the function to be something else. E.g.

```
void safeFreeImpl(void** pp);
#define safeFree(p) safeFreeImpl((void**)&(p))
```

Change `tool.c` accordingly.